# Inverse matrix in python (numpy/sympy)

Tags: numpy, sympy, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix (`A`) of order 8*8 which contains complex numbers.
I would like to calculate the inverse of that matrix, so I used `np.linalg.inv(b)` command but I got an error:

> UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'inv' input from dtype('O') to
> dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

It's worth to mention that:

```
In [169]: type(A)
Out[169]: numpy.matrix
In [171]:type(A[0,0])
Out[171]: sympy.core.mul.Mul
```

How can I calculate the inverse of that matrix? I have been a little confused, in which library should I search for? NumPy or SymPy? since the matrix type is NumPy however its component is SymPy.
Thanks

Comment: `inv` does work, if your array has the right `dtype`.  `object` is not the right dtype.  Show that array, some elements if not all.

Comment: Your array, or `np.matrix` is object dtype because it contains `sympy` expressions.  Numeric inv code cannot handle that kind of symbolic calculation.  `sympy` has an `inv`, I believe it's in the `Matrix` subpackage.  Search the docs.   Mixing sympy and numpy is rarely a good idea.

Comment: You need to use a SymPy Matrix rather than a NumPy matrix because NumPy cannot work with the symbolic expressions in your matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for your feedback. I checked the docs. I found matrix.inv() or matrix.inverse_ADJ() or matrix.inverse_GE() or martrix.inverse_LU(). However, none of those work. when I type A.inv() or matrix.inverse_GE(), I neither get any errors nor answers. It seems it takes a lot of time to calculate. I was waiting for an hour but nothing happens.